# Tensorflow - training custom model on dataset

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I feel it's something minor I'm missing, but can't seem to figure out what it is.
I'm trying to train a very simple model on **cassava** dataset, but when I call the `fit` function, the input name doesn't match the expected name. I tried naming the input layer to match the model, but tf insists on appending _input to the layer name causing conflict. I'm sure it's a fairly typical use-case for the tfds and it must be something trivial.

The Error:

```
ValueError: Missing data for input "flatten_input". You passed a data dictionary with keys ['image', 'image/filename', 'label']. Expected the following keys: ['flatten_input']
```

I borrowed the viewing code from a github project and that one definitely works as I can view the loaded data.

```
# tensorflow 2.x core api
import logging
from mlflow.models import infer_signature
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow import keras as K

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

#############################################################################################################
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot(examples, predictions=None):
  # Get the images, labels, and optionally predictions
  images = examples['image']
  labels = examples['label']
  batch_size = len(images)
  if predictions is None:
    predictions = batch_size * [None]

  # Configure the layout of the grid
  x = np.ceil(np.sqrt(batch_size))
  y = np.ceil(batch_size / x)
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(x * 6, y * 7))

  for i, (image, label, prediction) in enumerate(zip(images, labels, predictions)):
    # Render the image
    ax = fig.add_subplot(int(x), int(y), i+1)
    ax.imshow(image, aspect='auto')
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])

    # Display the label and optionally prediction
    x_label = 'Label: ' + name_map[class_names[label]]
    if prediction is not None:
      x_label = 'Prediction: ' + name_map[class_names[prediction]] + '\n' + x_label
      ax.xaxis.label.set_color('green' if label == prediction else 'red')
    ax.set_xlabel(x_label)

  plt.show()
  
  
# dataset, info = tfds.load('cassava', with_info=True)
dataset, info = tfds.load("cassava", shuffle_files=True, with_info=True)
print("INFO:\n", info)

# Extend the cassava dataset classes with 'unknown'
class_names = info.features['label'].names + ['unknown']

# Map the class names to human readable names
name_map = dict(
    cmd='Mosaic Disease',
    cbb='Bacterial Blight',
    cgm='Green Mite',
    cbsd='Brown Streak Disease',
    healthy='Healthy',
    unknown='Unknown')

print(len(class_names), 'classes:')
print(class_names)
print([name_map[name] for name in class_names])


def preprocess_fn(data):
  image = data['image']

  # Normalize [0, 255] to [0, 1]
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
  image = image / 255.

  # Resize the images to 224 x 224
  image = tf.image.resize(image, (224, 224))

  data['image'] = image
  return data


def create_model(type="default", n_classes=6):
    if type == "something":
        pass
    else:
        model = K.Sequential()
# naming the below layer with name argument still appends the _input to the actually name
        model.add(K.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(244, 244, 3)))
        model.add(K.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"))
        model.add(K.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
        model.add(K.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
        model.add(K.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
        model.add(K.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax"))
        model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=K.optimizers.Adam(0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model


# batch = dataset['validation'].map(preprocess_fn).batch(25).as_numpy_iterator()
# examples = next(batch)
# plot(examples)
print(tf.__version__)

model = create_model()
model.fit(dataset["train"], epochs=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could consider looking at this tf example using **tensorflow_datasets**: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/transfer_learning.

Accordingly, you could re-write your dataloader code as follows

```
dataset = tfds.load("cassava",
    split=["train[:40%]", "train[40%:50%]", "train[50%:60%]"],
    as_supervised=True, shuffle_files=True, with_info=False)
```

Define a new data preprocessing function such that it accommodates both image resizing and batch creation

```
def preprocess(dataset, img_size, batch_size):
    
    train_ds, validation_ds, test_ds = dataset

    # Image resizing
    train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (tf.image.resize(x, img_size), y))
    validation_ds = validation_ds.map(lambda x, y: (tf.image.resize(x, img_size), y))
    test_ds = test_ds.map(lambda x, y: (tf.image.resize(x, img_size), y))

    # Define the batches
    train_ds = train_ds.cache().batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=10)
    validation_ds = validation_ds.cache().batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=10)
    test_ds = test_ds.cache().batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=10)

    return train_ds, validation_ds, test_ds
```

Then, you should be able to train your model

```
train_ds, validation_ds, test_ds = preprocess(dataset, img_size=(244, 244), batch_size=32)
model.fit(train_ds, epochs=5, validation_data=validation_ds)
```

Hope this helps!